# create associated record with new object in Django

Tags: django

I'm using `Django 2`

I have two models

```
class Chapter(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class ChapterQuestion(models.Model):
    chapter = models.ForeignKey(Chapter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    word = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    definition = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.word
```

I want to be able to add multiple `questions` while creating `chapter`.
All will be done using single form only.

The view so far I have written is

```
class NewChapter(CreateView):
    template_name = 'courses/chapter/new_chapter.html'
    model = Chapter
    fields = ['name']

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(NewChapter, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        course = Course.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['course_id'])
        if course is None:
            messages.error(self.request, 'Course not found')
            return reverse('course:list')
        context['course'] = course

        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
        form.instance.course = Course.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['course_id'])
        form.save()

        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('course:detail', self.kwargs['course_id'])
```

But couldn't understand how to start. Any guide or tutorial will be appreciable.

Comment: [Django Formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/formsets/) as designed for specifically this task.

Comment: This answers to my multiple form question. But how to used associated model in form?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `CreateView` supports formsets, so you'll have to use a regular class based view or a function view.

When you create the form class for `ChapterQuestion` model, keep in mind to `exclude` the `chapter` foreignkey field.

Then, create your formset. [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/formsets/) will guide you through that.

Now, in your view, you can do this:

```
# assuming you'll use a regular class based view

def post(self, request):
    form = ChapterForm(request.POST)
    formset = ChapterQuestionFormset(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
        chapter = form.save() # first, save the chapter

        for f in formset: # loop through all the forms in formset
            question = f.save(commit=False)
            question.chapter = chapter # set the chapter
            question.save() # save the question to db

        return redirect('success')
```